# Preventing data mismatch in joining table with a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am making a stock management system  with different branches to manage sepearately. 
I have a list of branches with different branch Id's.
I am passing branch id as query string in url .

On the Database side I have 3 separate table to store  Item detail , Daily Data, Update Data

1. Item Detail Table (stock_item_detail)

   ```
   item_id |  item_code |  item_unit |  alert_limit | item_name | Branch_id
   1       | bc001      |     kgs     |   50        | Rice Flour | 1
   ```
2. Daily Data Table (stock_daily_data)

   ```
   item_code |quantity_used |   date      | stock_left| branch_id
   bc001  |    5         | 18-11-2017 |      45    | 1 `
   ```
3. Update Data (stock_update_data)

   ```
   item_code | remarks | quantity | date    | branch_id
   bc001    |pur0123   | 50       | 17-11-2017 | 1`
   ```

I get the list of items for a particular date ordered by recent remarks by executing the query

```
With cte as (
    select d.item_code,
           item_name,
           item_unit,
           alert_limit,
           d.quantity_used,
           d.stock_left,
           d.date 
    from stock_item_detail p join stock_daily_data d on d.item_code=p.item_code 
    where d.branch_id ='1' 
    ) 
    select * 
    from cte c cross apply 
    ( 
        select top 1 remarks 
        from stock_update_data ps 
        where ps.item_code= c.item_code and c.date='18-11-2017' order by date 
    ) b(remarks);
```

**if the above query gives an empty result**

```
INSERT stock_daily_data (item_code,date,quantity_used,stock_left ,branch_id) 
select distinct item_code,'18-11-2017',0,stock_left,'1' 
from 
(
    select  stock_item_detail.item_code, 
            stock_daily_data.stock_left, 
            row_number() over (partition by stock_daily_data.item_code order by stock_daily_data.date desc) as rn 
    from stock_item_detail join stock_daily_data on stock_item_detail.item_code = stock_daily_data.item_code ) tt where rn = 1;
```

Now the problem that I am facing is all the item irrespective of thier branch id are getting copied in daily data table with a paricular branch id .
Please let me know where am I wrong.
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which is the version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: SQL server 2012

Comment: The cte execution ceases after the select..) b (remarks) and has no relationship with the insert.

Comment: I think you may need a MERGE

Comment: I guess the issue is with the insert query

Comment: How do I change the insert query such that it inserts the item with a particular branch_id